# How can I copy a file and paste it as a different name?

Tags: rename, cp, file-copy, mv, clipboard

I have a file `test.txt` in directory `A/B`. I want to copy `test.txt` to `A/C` and rename it `newtest.txt`.

I know I can use the `cp` and `mv` commands to do this, but the issue is that there already is a `test.txt` in `A/C`, and there's already a `newtest.txt` in `A/B` and I don't want to overwrite either of those files.

I know I technically can do what I want with `mv test.txt ./verynewtest.txt && cp verynewtest.txt ../C && mv verynewtest.txt test.txt && cd ../C && mv verynewtest.txt newtest.txt`, but that seems really long.

Is there a faster/better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do

```
$ cd A/B
$ cp test.txt ../C/newtest.txt
```

Use

```
$ cp -i test.txt ../C/newtest.txt
```

to check whether `../C/newtest.txt` (i.e., `A/C/newtest.txt`) already exists
and ask for confirmation. 
(I almost never *deliberately* overwrite files,
so I alias `cp` to `cp -i` to get this protection every time I do a `cp`. 
But it’s also wise just to be careful not to clobber files
you don’t want to clobber, and not rely on aliases to save you.)

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize that `cp` could copy to a file name, not just a directory. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
.
`-- A
    |-- B
    |   |-- newtest.txt
    |   `-- test.txt
    `-- C
        `-- test.txt
```

And you want

```
.
`-- A
    |-- B
    |   |-- newtest.txt
    |   `-- test.txt
    `-- C
        |-- newtest.txt
        `-- test.txt
```

Where `A/C/newtest.txt` is a copy of `A/B/test.txt`.

The command

```
cp A/B/test.txt A/C/newtest.txt
```

would do that.

Comment: Helpful, but not quite. I want to *copy* it, so that `test.txt` also remains in `B`

Comment: Just use `cp` instead of `mv`, as in G-Man's answer.

Comment: Then use `cp` instead of `mv`.